# Crossing of strings

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, curves, planar-graphs

There are two strings of color red and blue. They are made to cross each other odd number of times (greater than one) without any self crossing. Is it always possible that there will be pair of crossings which are adjacent on both the strings ?

Comment: One is an odd number.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: It seems true to me, but I don't see where the odd hypothesis is needed ! (It seems true to me for all numbers greater than 1)

Comment: I read it somewhere for odd numbers. I am a bit skeptical in hasty generalization. But yeah it seems true to me for all numbers in general. This makes me think in direction of an inductive proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete Answer updated :

This is wrong for all $n>3$. Robert gave a solution for 4, and I gave a solution for 5, there is also a solution for 6. From those solutions, you can always add 3 points to get another larger solution (and you can repeat and add another 3 points as long as you want), which lead to all possible n without adjacent crossings.

Here a seven crossings from the four crossings solution :

[image]

You can see that you can always extend the blue string (from the end that is at the third crossing from left) and add 3 more points (two points will be between the second and third crossing, and the middle point will be right after the last rightmost crossing). There are similar solutions from 5 points and 6 points.

For 5 crossings, a counter-example :

[image: Counter Example]

Comment: Nice! So it seems intuition doesn't quite work for this problem. But I have a feeling we might not be able to get a counter example for more than 5 crossings.

Comment: @user138359 I can and I did. Please verify if it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

For an even number of crossings, try

[image]

(This is not an answer to the original question, but I don't know how to put an image in a comment)